# Ubuntu: setting timeout value on do-release-upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, timeout, upgrade

Having an issue upgrading from 9.10 to 10.04 LTS.  Keeps failing on a package in the repo, but if I copy and paste the URL into `wget`, it downloads the Packages.gz, albeit after almost 12-15 seconds as I'm assuming the timeout value in `do-release-upgrade` is shorter than `wget` by default.

I didn't see any parameters you can specify to change the timeout value calling `--help`.  Looking through `do-release-upgrade` script had nothing obvious as far as timeout was concerned either.

My plan right now (unless I hear otherwise from my SF brethren) is to wait until after-hours and assume that there's some network congestion somewhere between this box and the repos (which I can't check as I don't really have access to the network at this client location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found out how, but routing/network issue "went away" at the clients/ISP, so was able to do upgrade successfully without changing the time out.